# Getting info from many tables

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-2

I have 4 tables: question_tags, tags, questions and users.

> Question structure is: q_id, q_title, q_content, q_date, q_author (id
>   from users table).
>
> Tags structure is: tag_id, tag_name, tag_description.
>
> Question_tags structure is: id, tag_id, q_id.

I want ot list all questions and next to every question title to show and its tags. I've come up with this so far:

```
$this->db->join('users', 'q_author = users.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('q_id', 'desc');
$this->db->limit($per_page, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get('questions');
```

But have no ideas about the tags. (also I'm using CodeIgniter)

P.S. Every question can has more than one tag.

database table tags codeigniter-2

Comment: I think you can try selecting `GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name)`  with a LEFT JOIN between `question.q_id=question_tags.q_id` and a JOIN where `question_tags.tag_id=tags.tag_id` and a `GROUP BY(q_id)` (I could write the query in MySQL, but don't know how it's done in codeigniter). That'd return your info and a comma-separated list of tag names for each question.

Comment: I tried this: `SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) FROM questions LEFT JOIN users ON q_author = users.id LEFT JOIN question_tags ON questions.q_id=question_tags.q_id  LEFT JOIN tags ON questions.q_id = question_tags.q_id GROUP BY questions.q_id`, but it returns all tags, not these for this question. Where is my mistake?

Comment: That second `LEFT JOIN` (to `tags`) should be `ON tags.tag_id = questions_tags.tag_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I finally came up with this:
`SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( tags.tag_name ) 
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN users ON q_author = users.id
LEFT JOIN question_tags ON questions.q_id = question_tags.q_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = question_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY questions.q_id`

Comment: keep in mind the default limit of group_concat (1024), you may have trimmed data if some question tags exceed that limit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have different queries if you want to avoid returning duplicate data in your main query. Because you have many tags related to each question you should loop through your question results and within each loop iteration query the tags for that question.